# Minimal access needed to manage developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

What is the minimal security setup is needed to grant person access to make changes to **Developer portal**, but have no rights to amend other objects within API Management service?

Answer (score 0):

The minimal permission is `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users/token/action`.

If you want to restrict the access of a user, you could create a [custom RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with the permission above.

Here is a powershell sample to create the role, make sure you have installed  the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.6.1) powershell module first.

```
Import-Module Az 
Connect-AzAccount 
$contributorRole = Get-AzRoleDefinition "API Management Service Contributor" 
$customRole = $contributorRole 
$customRole.Id = $null
$customRole.Name = "APIM New Portal Admin" 
$customRole.Description = "This role gives the user ability to log in to the new Developer portal as administrator" 
$customRole.Actions = "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users/token/action" 
$customRole.IsCustom = $true 
$customRole.AssignableScopes.Clear() 
$customRole.AssignableScopes.Add('/subscriptions/<subscription-id>') 
New-AzRoleDefinition -Role $customRole
```

After creating the role, assign the role to the user, the following PowerShell command demonstrates how to assign the role to a user `user1` at the lowest scope to avoid granting unnecessary permissions to the user:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName "user1@contoso.com" -RoleDefinitionName "APIM New Portal Admin" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<apim-service-name>/users/1"
```

For more details, see [What permissions do I need to edit the developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal#what-permissions-do-i-need-to-edit-the-developer-portal).

Comment: I followed this, however role with this only action is not granting access as such to Developer portal. Based on the documentation you are referring to, it starts with: `If you're seeing the Oops. Something went wrong. Please try again later. error when you open the portal in the administrative mode, you may be lacking the required permissions (RBAC).` So assumption that this kind of access needed once basic access is already granted.

Comment: @Rapolas I don't think so, did you sign out and sign in again to the Azure portal for the new permissions to take effect?